# To assign flashvars value from input value

Tags: javascript, flashvars

I am trying to assign the URL from a input value that's parsed by PHP to FlashVars using javascript

```
<input id="feed" type="hidden" value="http://localhost/photo/" />

... other HTML code goes here ...

var flashvars = {
   feed: document.getElementById('feed').value(),

   ... other flashvars code goes here ...

}
```

But this doesn't seem to work, is there anyway to pull this off? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `()`, value is not a function.

Change

```
feed: document.getElementByID('feed').value(),
```

to

```
feed: document.getElementByID('feed').value,
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out, but it still doesn't work. It works if I assign the static string directly like feed:"http://localhost/photo/" but not when using feed:document.getElementByID('feed').value

Comment: Okay, I had to change to flashvars['feed'] = document.getElementById('flashvar-feed').value;